# How to store html characters in mysql and display them correctly

Tags: mysql, html, editor, character

Not sure if I am asking this correctly.  But I am using a Jquery HTML Editor cleditor so that the users can load html text.  When I insert this into my db(mysql) and want to display the outcome it takes out any html characters it had like: `<p>`, `<span>`, and so on.  So when I go view it, it shows like this:

```
class=\"noticia_texto\">jlasdfklsfklaf
```

which obviously it's not readable.  Help please?  Should I be using anything at the time of inserting or displaying or both?  Also my datatype is set to Blob.

Comment: If you look inside the database (with phpMyAdmin) is the HTML text correct there? If not, check in other places you know the string passes through to localise the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does NOT strip html tags. If they're being removed upon insertion (or retrieval), then it's something in your code doing it, not MySQL.

Given that the quotes in your snippet are escaped, you've almost certainly got magic_quotes enabled, and/or a home-brew SQL escaping function run amok.

Comment: on insertion I have mysql_escape_string($_POST['text']) should I not use this?

Comment: That's exactly what you should be using. However, since you've still got escapes in the DB, that means something is causing double-escaping - most likely magic_quotes. Check what the contents of `$_POST['text']` is BEFORE you insert it into the db.

Comment: when I echo de text it shows just how I inserted it in the text field.  all the proper tags are there.

Comment: Then something in your retrieval code is doing the stripping.

Comment: Ok somehow I was able to keep it from taking it out, but now I am having the issue where it puts the backslash for quotes in class like class=\"...\" which obvoisly html doesn't recognize that...help please?

Comment: somwhere you're doing extra SQL escaping where it's not necessary, or your PHP install has magic_quotes enabled. Without code samples or configuration details, impossible to say which.

Comment: Ok I found this line in the php.ini file

  ; - magic_quotes_gpc = Off         [Performance]

Do I need to comment this or just delete the line?

Comment: Nevermind found it, there was another line that had it turned on.  Thank you for you patience :)

Comment: You can use 'phpinfo()' to see what the "local" setting are at any given point in a script. It will always report the master and "what's in effect right now" values.